# PHP Cronjob does not execute

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am running Ubunutu Linux server, PHP5, Apache2 and am having trouble getting any sort of cronjob to run through the crontab.

I edit the crontab using

> crontab -e

I save the file I want to run:

> */5 * * * * php /home/user/public_html/crx/cronx.php

it saves fine.  I can run the file from the console and goes through fine.  I can't even find any existing logs for the file.  I checked cron was running, stopped and started... no change.

The current php file is just a simple test script that inserts a single line into a database.

I checked the permissions for the file and has read and write.  Am absolutely stumped.  I can't seem to get ANYTHING to run through cron.  Is there something I can run to test permissions?

**EDIT** 
I have also tried the following command

> - - - - - /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/crx/cronx.php

I used whereis php and which php to locate and confirm it is all running in the right area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `*` values for your times.

Also, cron may not have a `PATH` set up correctly to use PHP.

Instead try:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/crx/cronx.php
```

Where `/usr/bin/php` is the actual path to PHP.  From the console you can run `which php` to see the path to the PHP binary you should use.

EDIT: Here are a couple of more things to try in order to troubleshoot:

```
# see if cron is running just by having it create a file
*/5 * * * * touch /tmp/crontab-$(date +%s)
```

Another option:

Set the permissions of your PHP script to `755`, and change the beginning to:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// rest of script
```

Then change your cron tab to:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/user/public_html/crx/cronx.php
```

I'm still not sure if cron is the issue or the running of the PHP script.

Comment: I have gone through all options using the full path to PHP and found that it is in /usr/bin/php but still doesnt work.  I noticed there are too many stars, but thats juts in my post, i checked the cron and its got the correct amount. Is there any way I can see a log of the error? or what is happening?

Comment: If it doesn't already, have your script output some content via echo.  Then in your crontab file add `MAILTO=username` or `MAILTO=you@youremail.com` and it should send an email containing the output of the job.  YOu can also try creating a file in the script like `touch('/tmp/cron-' . time());` to confirm its running.

Comment: hmmm.  added MAILTO=my@email.com to the cron tab file but nothing coming through.

Comment: I think I worked it out.  I was editing the crontab under my console user, when i sudo crontab-e it gave me a different crontab file.

Comment: Nope... still no email giving me anything, no sign anything is running.

Comment: I can't see any errors in the mail log, nor can I even see a cron log

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install sendmail` just in case.

Comment: Ok It appears that it can't include my php function definitions file.  I am guessing because it doesnt have permissions to do so.  Will have to have a look at the permissions

Comment: That's some progress. I jsut made an edit to my answer but you can probably ignore it now.  You are seeing some PHP errors output in the email from cron?

Comment: yeah, it seems to be a permission issue in my php file it is crashing when trying to 
> require('defs/func_defs.php');
saying there is no such file or directory.  I am guessing it is permissions for cron which is equally challenging, but at least it appears I have narrowed down the fault!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15150/discussion-between-elzaer-and-drew010)